# Turn on/off wifi radio when computer suspends/resumes

Tags: wifi, manjaro, suspend

I am running Manjaro on a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 and I have issues with the Wifi not working after resuming from suspend. My current solution is to turn off the wifi radio using

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

before I suspend, then turning it back on when I resume.

Is there anywhere I can put a script so that it will automatically run these commands adjacent to suspending/resuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably using Systemd thus have a look at the [System sleep state logic](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html). So you might drop a script into `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` which runs the commands.

**wifi-hack.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
   nmcli radio wifi off
elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
   nmcli radio wifi on
fi
```

And make the script executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi-hack.sh
```

However be advised

> Note that scripts or binaries dropped in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` are intended for local use only and **should be considered hacks**. If applications want to react to system suspend/hibernation and resume, they should rather use the [Inhibitor interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit).

Thus have a look at [Inhibitor interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit) do do the proper way.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll look into the Inhibitor interface.

Comment: IMHO As you don't create an app I guess just putting the script there and you are fine.